# Spanning cells in dynamic table in FOP

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xmltable

My problem is that I have a table with dynamic length and I need to span 3 Rows over 3 cells where the other rows have single cell length.

I get a generated XML file with values like

```
<item>
  <val1>a</val1>
  <val2>b</val2>
  <val3_1>a1</val3_1>
  <val3_2>b1</val3_2>
  <val3_3>c1</val3_3>
  <val4>c</val4>
</item>
```

and the table should look like

```
 | val1: |-------val1---------| |-------val1---------|
 | val2: |-------val2---------| |-------val2---------|
 | val3: |val3_1|val3_2|val3_3| |val3_1|val3_2|val3_3|
 | val4: |--------val4--------| |--------val4--------|
```

I have this source:

```
<fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
<fo:table-body>

    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"
            background-color="{$tabbgcolor}" width="50mm">
            <fo:block>
                               val1:
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid"
                number-columns-spanned="3" border-width="2pt" background-color="{$tabbgcolor}"
                font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="val1" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"
            background-color="{$var_color_reserve}">
            <fo:block text-indent="1em" wrap-option="wrap">
                val2:
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid"
                number-columns-spanned="3" border-width="2pt" background-color="{$tabbgcolor}"
                text-align="center">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="val2" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"
            background-color="{$var_color_reserve}">
            <fo:block text-indent="1em" wrap-option="wrap">
                Val3:
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>


        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="2pt"
                background-color="{$tabbgcolor}" text-align="center">
                <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                    <xsl:value-of select="val3_1" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="2pt"
                background-color="{$tabbgcolor}" text-align="center">
                <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                    <xsl:value-of select="val3_2" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="instzahl">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="2pt"
                background-color="{$tabbgcolor}" text-align="center">
                <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                    <xsl:value-of select="val3_3" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>




    </fo:table-row>

    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"
            background-color="{$var_color_reserve}">
            <fo:block text-indent="1em" wrap-option="wrap">
                val4:
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid"
                number-columns-spanned="3" border-width="2pt" background-color="{$tabbgcolor}"
                text-align="center">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="val4" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>


</fo:table-body>
```

The problems are the following:

1. The values are parsed wrongly: I get all values val3_1 then all val3_2 and then all val3_3 instead of val3_1 val3_2 val3_3 and the next turn val3_1 val3_2 val3_3 and so on.
2. The spanning doesn't work. I get that is because I don't now how many cells I will have in the end because I can't foresee how many items will be in the xml file at the time it is generated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it solved here is the code:

```
                    <fo:table-body>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"  width="50mm">
                                <fo:block>
                                  val1: 
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" number-columns-spanned="3"  border-width="2pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val1" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" >
                                <fo:block  wrap-option="wrap">
                                     val2:
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" number-columns-spanned="3" border-width="2pt" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val2" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="2pt" >
                                <fo:block  wrap-option="wrap">
                                    val3:
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>


                            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val3_1" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>

                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid"  border-width="1pt" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val3_2" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>

                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"  text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val3_3" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </xsl:for-each>


                        </fo:table-row>


                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="2pt" >
                                <fo:block  wrap-option="wrap">
                                    val4
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        <xsl:for-each select="item">
                                <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" number-columns-spanned="3" border-width="2pt" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="val4" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>


                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```